# Nesting in Dart PolymerElement in another PolymerElement

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm trying to nesting in Dart PolymerElements in *another* PolymerElement like this.

```
@CustomTag('test-box')
class Box extends PolymerElement{
    @observable List<Child> childs = new List<Child>();

    Box.created() : super.created() { }
}

@CustomTag('test-child')
class Child extends PolymerElement{
    Child.created() : super.created() { }
}
```

and then in **testbox.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="testchild.html">
<polymer-element name="test-box">
  <template>
    <div>
      <ol name="child-list">
        <template repeat="{{child in childs}}">
          {{child}}
        </template>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="testbox.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Is that possible with Dart/Polymer? All my tries are failed.
I want to handle html nodes like classes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your link element must inside the polymer-element. Also, {{child}} is an expression, you want a tag instead: <test-child></test-child>. See https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/tree/master/web for lots of examples.

Comment: Actually this does not work. It will insert one new test-child element per each list item, but this would be not items from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a model object to pass data to a child element via published property.

Check this example: https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/tree/master/web/observable_objects_inside_list_changes

Comment: a working solution but not what I would prefer. In JS there is no problem to store/create not embedded html nodes. It seems there is currently no other way in dart-polymer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the children nodes to the box, for example:

```
@CustomTag('test-box') 
class Box extends PolymerElement{
@observable List<Child> childs = new List<Child>();

    Box.created() : super.created() { 

    }

    void _addChildren(List<Child> children) {
        children.forEach((Child c) {
           this.children.add(c);
        }  
    }

    @override void attached() { super.attached(); _addChildren(childs); }
}
```

Then you can monitor changes on childs using `observable` API to reflect the changes on the array.

Beware that `Child` object should be created with `new Element.tag("test-child")`.

But IMHO the best solution is the one offered by @Leksat using a more pure MVC approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same problem and solved it using some kind of proxy element.
ProxyElement Dart code:

```
library ProxyElement;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('proxy-element')
class ProxyElement extends PolymerElement {

  @published PolymerElement target;

  ProxyElement.created() : super.created();

  attached() {
    shadowRoot.querySelector('#proxy').append(target);
  }

}
```

And its HTML code:

> ```
> <link rel="import" href="../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
>
> <polymer-element name="proxy-element">
>   <template>
>     <style>
>       :host {
>         display: inline;
>       }
>     </style>
>
>     <template if="{{target == null}}">
>       No target element defined.
>     </template>
>     <template if="{{target != null}}"> 
>       <div id="proxy"></div>      
>     </template>
>   </template>
>   <script type="application/dart" src="proxy_element.dart"></script>
> </polymer-element>
> ```

Usage:

```
...
<template repeat="{{child in children}}">
    <proxy-element target="{{child}}"></proxy-element>
</template>
...
```